# How to get the base url?

Tags: uri

(Drupal 7.22)
We need to create a menu link to an external site, "https://example.com/some/path"
`/some/path` is static, whereas "https://example.com" depends on site instance, such as

web-dev.example.com

web-qa.exmple.com

web-rc.example.com

I would think that this could be accomplished with `$GLOBALS['base_root']`;
for example:
`$url = $GLOBALS['base_root'] . '/some/path';`

On local (laptop) `$GLOBALS['base_root']` resolves correctly, but on CentoOS
`$GLOBALS['base_root']` resolves to `[http://default]`

How do we dynamically get the actual current site domain?
This can't be so hard, what are we missing?

Answer (score 9):

If this is a fully bootstrapped Drupal site, the superglobal `$base_url`, should get you what you want. See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/7

However, these globals are not initialized until Drupal is fully bootstrapped.

If you need to sniff the base URL before Drupal is fully bootstrapped you can use the PHP [`$_SERVER` superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

For example:

```
function _get_base_url(){
  $protocol = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "off")) ? "https" : "http";
  return $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

Comment: Yea, I'm still missing something here.  In an install hook, I have  watchdog('menu_link-base_url', $GLOBALS['base_url']);
  watchdog('menu_link-base_path', $GLOBALS['base_path']);
  watchdog('menu_link-base_root', $GLOBALS['base_root']); and that returns: "http://default" (base_url) "/" (base_path) and "http://default" (base_root), although the $GLOBALS['base_url'] and $GLOBALS['base_root'] correctly return the current site domain when referenced from page.tpl.php (for debugging).  Why different from an install hook on the same site?

Comment: I got what I needed by setting $base_url in settings.php: $base_url = 'http://www.example.com';   But it means we need to manage settings.php for different deployment environments    Is this the only way the $base_url is set, or does it depend on other php or server settings as well?

Comment: I think it's fine to have different settings.php files for different environments. Usually I never commit settings.php file to any version control systems.

Comment: If you're installing the module via drush, you may get a default url. If so, you can use a drush alias, or pass the drush parameter --uri=http://www.example.com

Answer (score 1):

For the case when Drupal is fully bootstrapped, that is when `$base_url` works, the [`url()` function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) is a potentially more elegant alternative:

```
$make_absolute = array('absolute' => TRUE);
$url = url("some/path", $make_absolute);
```