# Automatic base URL not picking up https://

Tags: ssl, uri

My Drupal site is using https:// but the base URL is not using it.

My site therefore is not opening properly. Is there any way to make Drupal pick up the correct base URL?

I tried adding `$base_url` in settings.php but it's giving me this error:

> GET https://example.com/js/admin_menu/cache/6599fa6c7ea0ac232a88eaa63e957878 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Forgive me for asking obvious, have you cleared all caches? `drush cc all`?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the $base_url on the protocol:

```
  $base_url = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 'https://' : 'http://') . 'www.yoururl.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need same thing : [How to get the base url?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78992/how-to-get-the-base-url).

```
function _get_base_url(){
  $protocol = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "off")) ? "https" : "http";
  return $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```